# Difference among "when it comes to", "as far as" and "regarding"

Tags: differences

I was wondering if there's any difference among these three, maybe some of them are a bit formal and some are colloquial in daily conversation? Thanks in advance!

For example,

> I'm as good a cook as she is except when it comes to pastry.

Comment: You'd need 'I'm as good a cook as she is except as far as pastry goes.'

Comment: Any of them is possible. Which you prefer is simply a matter of personal opinion.

Answer (score 1):

These phrases overlap a lot. There are shadows of difference but they are weak.

When it comes to ... may suggest that you have already considered some implied or stated precedent. *I like wine but when it comes to spirits, leave me out.*

As far as ... may suggest a complete overview of the following argument. *As far as I can see, there will be no end to this Brexit disaster.*

Regarding ... may have the feeling of initiating a discussion. *Regarding grammar, there are many inconsistencies.*